# Remove library from pythonpath

Tags: pydev

I checked out `twisted` source code form svn and opened it using eclipse as a Python project. But I also have twisted installed in my system under `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`. So the imports in the source code imports the installed version and not the version I checked out from svn.

How can I remove the installed version from the libraries that PyDev searches?

Removing `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` from PYTHONPATH is not an option because twisted depends on some of the libraries in that directory ( such as `serial` library )

Answer (score 0):

When you make a launch in PyDev, it should add the PYTHONPATH of the project(s) before the PYTHONPATH of the interpreter, so, if you create a project with the twisted source code and set the PYTHONPATH (i.e.: source folder) for that project properly, it should find it before the one in the interpreter.

Note that other projects should reference the twisted project you configured in order to access it.